# Offline install of npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've got a script that automatically installs some npm packages (specifically karma, which I'd like to install with `--global`) on an EC2 instance on startup. The problem is that npm sometimes randomly fails, presumably due to network hiccups, though I'm not entirely sure what's going on.

To rule out the network, what I'd like to do is download the relevant files for npm and ask it to install karma based on the files as I download them from S3.

But how do I do that? How do I tell npm not to grab files from the central repository and to instead grab them from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first install `npmbox` module globally, This module creates an Offline package with all depedencies of given module. Then you could use `npmunbox` command to install that package to your offline machine.

To install npmbox: `npm install -g npmbox`

To create offline package of a module: `npmbox -v localtunnel`, It will generate a `localtunnel.npmbox` file to current directory. Copy that you your offline machine.

To install offline package: `npmunbox localtunnel.npmbox`

For more info: https://github.com/arei/npmbox

Comment: How do I install npmbox to an offline machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Simple and transparent tool to do `npm install` using npm's offline cache

Please see https://github.com/harish2704/npm-offline-registry

Answer (score 0):

**INSTALL PM2 OFFLINE:-**

> Tested on Node-v6.10.3 and Npm-3.10.10 on RHEL-7

**Go to machine with internet connection:-**

```
#npm install -g npmbox
#npmbox npmbox
#scp npmbox.npmbox root@offline-server-ip:.
```

**Go to machine without internet connection :-**

```
#ssh  root@offline-server-ip 
#tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions -xvzf npmbox.npmbox
#npm install --global --cache ./.npmbox.cache --optional --cache-min 99999999999 --shrinkwrap false npmbox
```

**Go to machine with internet connection:-**

```
#npm install pm2 -g
#npmbox pm2
#scp pm2.npmbox root@offline-server-ip:.
```

**Go to machine without internet connection :-**

```
#npmunbox pm2.npmbox --global
#pm2 ls
```